# Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace 'MASS' is imported by 'vegan' so cannot be unloaded

Tags: r, r-package, checkpoint

```
checkpoint("2019-12-11",R.version = "3.5.3",scanForPackages = FALSE,verbose = TRUE,use.knitr=FALSE, auto.install.knitr = FALSE, scan.rnw.with.knitr = TRUE,forceInstall = FALSE, forceProject = FALSE, use.lock = TRUE)

r$> packageVersion('checkpoint')
[1] '0.4.9'

r$> library(knitr)

r$> library(rmarkdown)

r$> library(MASS)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Package 'MASS' version 7.3.51.3 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace 'MASS' is imported by 'vegan' so cannot be unloaded
```

When I face this error,I `remove.packages('MASS')` and reinstall,but cannot solve this problem.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Seems you have `vegan` package loaded. Try `unloadNamespace(vegan)` before removing `MASS`. There also might be other dependencies though.

Comment: @jay.sf,I never `library(vegan)` in my script.

Comment: Ok, then `vegan` is a dependency of another package you've loaded, inspecting `sessionInfo()` might help.

Comment: @jay.sf,loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 `[1] Rcpp_1.0.1            lattice_0.20-38       permute_0.9-5         MASS_7.3-51.1         grid_3.5.3            jsonlite_1.6.1        nlme_3.1-137          stats4_3.5.3          vegan_2.5-4           Matrix_1.2-15
[11] pbivnorm_0.6.0        splines_3.5.3         tools_3.5.3           dcurver_0.9.1         compiler_3.5.3        GPArotation_2014.11-1 Deriv_3.8.5           parallel_3.5.3        mnormt_1.5-5          cluster_2.0.7-1
[21] mgcv_1.8-27         lavaan_0.6-3        mirt_1.30`,I am curious how these packages loaded at begining.

Comment: Hmm I don't know which package of the imports `vegan`. You'll probably have to go through them for debugging. Use e.g. `help(package="MASS")` and read line `Depends:...` Maybe just try to restart R beforehand.

Comment: Yeah,  _some_ of your packages depends on `vegan`, `sessionInfo()` says: "loaded via a namespace and not attached", so it is locked, I would try to proceed as suggested.

Comment: I don't know your working environment, seems though that you don't have that much `library` calls in your script. There are packages around that load lots of dependencies. Actual `library` calls appear as _attached_  packages and the dependencies appear as _loaded via namespace_ . Another option is your `Rprofile.site` might be customized and contain some auto-loads, but only if someone has edited it, you may want to read: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html

Answer (score 3):

```
unloadNamespace('mirt')
unloadNamespace('vegan')
```

solved this problem.

But I am curious when I open R terminal in vs code,then `sessionInfo()`,output as below:

```
[1] Rcpp_1.0.1            lattice_0.20-38       permute_0.9-5         MASS_7.3-51.1         grid_3.5.3            jsonlite_1.6.1        nlme_3.1-137          stats4_3.5.3          vegan_2.5-4           Matrix_1.2-15 [11] pbivnorm_0.6.0        splines_3.5.3         tools_3.5.3           dcurver_0.9.1         compiler_3.5.3        GPArotation_2014.11-1 Deriv_3.8.5           parallel_3.5.3        mnormt_1.5-5          cluster_2.0.7-1 [21] mgcv_1.8-27         lavaan_0.6-3
```

I don't know how this packages loaded automatically.